# How to open crystal reports in android

Tags: android, crystal-reports, helper, viewer

Please help me to open Crystal reports in android.Is there is any crystal report viewer for android?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use Google to get the answer?

Comment: Thanks.But i have tried a lot.

Comment: @MahiMali: What have you tried , whats your progress so far ?

Comment: the report or the output? because you can create html or pdf views... also if i remember a Crystal Report Viewer (flash based)... flash is available in android...

Comment: @yeradis: yes i want to create doc view or crystal report view as .net in android.can you help.

Comment: @MahiMali-Did you accomplished your goal. Because I need a similar feature in my Android app...can u please help..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would display them exported either as PDF's, or as HTML using a custom XML Exporting Format. Tricky if you're not familiar with XSL templates, so PDF's have been the easiest for me.

The built in HTML32/HTML40 exports often generate buggy looking results for complex reports